# Changing the Material UI's DatePicker's border color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

This is my DatePicker from material UI, the only thing I want is to change borderColor. I've tried classes, changing the theme's primary color, using WithStyles.. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `className` prop is not applied to the MUI DatePicker component currently. There is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/4942) for this bug.

Alternatively, you can pass `className` prop to `renderInput` prop like:

```
<DatePicker
    label="Birthdate"
    defaultValue={new Date()}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params} className="myDatePicker" />
    )}
/>
```

and apply the css on `fieldset` tag like:

```
.myDatePicker fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border-color: green;
}

.myDatePicker .Mui-focused fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border-color: red;
}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-date-picker-border-vclnq2) for a live working example of this usage.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up getting className's like this from html source code. Now I'm searching for hovering lol.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)

Comment: @İlker in my answer I include most of the customisations you might need, let me know if you are stuck in anything else, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to customise the default, hover and active styling for the border color. You can also do the same using styled components. Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-violet-1wyne0?file=/demo.tsx).

```
<DatePicker
        label="Birthdate"
        defaultValue={new Date()}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            sx={{
              '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
                '& fieldset': {
                  borderColor: 'red',
                },
                '&:hover fieldset': {
                  borderColor: 'green',
                },
                '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
                  borderColor: 'purple',
                },
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
```